# Majorana field Lagrangian in curved spacetime

Tags: quantum-field-theory, differential-geometry, spinors, qft-in-curved-spacetime, majorana-fermions

In this paper([An Exact Cosmological Solution of the Coupled
Einstein-Majorana Fermion-Scalar Field Equations](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0701025)), the Majorana field Lagrangian has been stated as

$\mathcal{L}_M = i \bar{\psi} \left(\gamma \wedge *\nabla\right) \psi - i m\bar{\psi}\psi*1$

where $\bar{\psi}$ is the charge conjugated spinor field $\bar{\psi}=\psi^{\dagger} \mathcal{C}$ with charge conjugation matrix, $\mathcal{C}=\gamma_0$.

In contrast to this, the same Majorana field Lagrangian has been written in this paper ([Variational Field Equations of a Majorana
Neutrino Coupled to Einstein’s Theory of
General Relativity](https://arxiv.org/abs/2209.10960)) as,

$\mathcal{L}_M = \dfrac{i}{2} \bar{\psi} *\gamma \wedge \nabla \psi + \dfrac{i}{2} m\bar{\psi}\psi*1$

Now even if the mass term is neglected, the rest parts of two Lagrangians aren't seem to be same in both the cases!

What am I missing and *what is the correct Lagrangian for a general Majorana field in curved spacetime?* Are these two Lagrangians similar (or somehow same) in some sense?

*Disclaimer:* I am not very much habituated in the exterior calculus, maybe that's why such confusion is arising.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would write the action (in $n=2,3,4$  mod 8, spacetime dimensions where Majorana's exist) in a more conventional form as
$$
S= \int d^n x \sqrt{-g}\frac 12  \bar \psi {\mathcal C}\gamma^a e_a^\mu \left(\partial_\mu + {\textstyle \frac 12} {\omega^{bc}}_\mu \sigma_{bc}+ m\right)\psi,
$$
where $\mathcal C$ is defined independently of the gamma-matrix representation by
${\mathcal C} \gamma^a {\mathcal C}^{-1} =- \gamma^{aT}$. I see no advantage to the differential form language, but it seems popular in some areas.  I do think that the factor of two is correct. The $i$'s are metric-signature dependent.

I have a longer answer here: [Do I need Gamma matrices in Majorana representation in the Lagrangian of a Majorana fermion?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/454475/do-i-need-gamma-matrices-in-majorana-representation-in-the-lagrangian-of-a-major?rq=1)

Comment: Can you please provide me the reference, where I can find more details about this Lagrangian?

Comment: My Majorana answers are drawn from my own paper:J. Phys. A: Math. Theor. 55 ( 2022 ) 205401, arXiv:2009.00518. There are many papers on Dirac in curved space.