# Energy-momentum tensor of Majorana field

Tags: general-relativity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, spinors, qft-in-curved-spacetime, majorana-fermions

The Majorana field action in curved spacetime, in general, is usually written as (see [this answer on Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/782584/332923))

$$\mathcal{A}_M = \displaystyle\int_\mathcal{M} d^4x ~ e \left\{\dfrac{1}{2} \bar{\psi}\Gamma^\mu D_\mu\psi - V\left(\psi,\bar{\psi}\right)\right\}$$

where $\bar{\psi} \equiv \psi^\dagger \mathcal{C}$ for $\mathcal{C}$ being the charge conjugation operator, $\Gamma^\mu \equiv e^\mu_{~b} \gamma^b$ is the generalized Dirac-Pauli matrices satisfying $\left\{\Gamma^\mu, \Gamma^\nu\right\} = 2g^{\mu\nu}$ and $$D_\mu \equiv \partial_\mu + \dfrac{1}{2} \omega_{\mu ab}\Sigma^{ab}$$ is the generalized covariant derivative; $\omega_{\mu ab} = e^\nu_{~a} \nabla_\mu e_{\nu b}$ are the Ricci rotation (or spin) coefficients and $\Sigma^{ab}=\dfrac{1}{4}\left[\gamma^a,\gamma^b\right]$ are the generators of the spinor representation of the Lorentz group. Here, $e$ is the determinant of the vierbein $e_\mu^{~a}$.

Now if one wants to derive the *Hilbert energy-momentum tensor*  of the Majorana spinor (on-shell) from this, what will be that expression? I guess, it would be

$$T_{\mu\nu}^{(M)} = \dfrac{1}{2} \bar{\psi}\Gamma_{(\mu} D_{\nu)}\psi - g_{\mu\nu} \mathcal{L}_M$$

in analogy with the energy-momentum tensor of the Dirac spinor. Will it be so?

**My attempt:** Following this paper ([Spinors, Inflation, and Non-Singular Cyclic Cosmologies](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0301129), here the energy-momentum tensor of the Dirac spinor has been obtained), one can write the Hilbert energy-momentum tensor as

$$T_{\mu\nu}^{(M)} = \dfrac{e_{\mu a}}{e} \dfrac{\delta \mathcal{A}_M}{\delta e^\nu_{~a}} = \dfrac{e_{\mu a}}{e} \displaystyle\int_\mathcal{M} d^4x ~e \left\{\dfrac{1}{2} \bar{\psi} \dfrac{\delta}{\delta e^\nu_{~a}} \left(\Gamma^\alpha D_\alpha\psi\right) - e_\nu^{~a} \mathcal{L}_M\right\}$$

$$\Longrightarrow T_{\mu\nu}^{(M)} = \dfrac{e_{\mu a}}{e} \displaystyle\int_\mathcal{M} d^4x ~e \left[\dfrac{1}{2} \bar{\psi} \gamma^b \dfrac{\delta}{\delta e^\nu_{~a}} \left\{e^\alpha_{~b} \left(\partial_\alpha + \dfrac{1}{2}\omega_{\alpha cd}\Sigma^{cd}\right)\right\} \psi - e_\nu^{~a} \mathcal{L}_M\right]$$

Now in order to simplify this, one needs the derivative of $e^\alpha_{~b}$ and $\omega_{\alpha cd}$ w.r.t. $e^\nu_{~a}$. But what will be those? I don't see any hope to reach the expression of energy-momentum tensor that I somehow guessed earlier!

Comment: There is some discussion of the derivative of the spin connection in the wikipedia article on the Belinfante-Rosenfeld stress–energy tensor